# How to make the output text attribute value as a hyperlink?

Tags: java, html, jsf

I should display the bookmarks as hyperlink.so on clicking the bookmark will take me to corresponding web page.Can any one tell me how should i achieve my goal?Thanks.

```
<html>
  <f:view>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h:form>
        <h1>Welcome to bookmark page</h1>
        <h:dataTable value="#{table.bookmark}" var="item" border="1" rows="10">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputLabel value="Bookmark table"></h:outputLabel>
          </f:facet> 
          <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputLabel value="Edit"></h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.editBookmark}" onclick="submit">
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
          </h:column>
          <h:column> 
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputLabel value="Sno"></h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{item.sno}" rendered="#{item.editBookmark}" size="10">      
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.sno}" rendered="#{not item.editBookmark}">
            </h:outputText>
          </h:column>
          <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputLabel value="Bookmarks"></h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{item.bookmark}" rendered="#{item.editBookmark}" size="10">
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.bookmark}" rendered="#{not item.editBookmark}">
            </h:outputText>
          </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton value="submit">
        </h:commandButton>
      </h:form>
    </body>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h:outputLink value="#{item.bookmark}" rendered="#{not item.editBookmark}" <h:outputText value = "#{item.bookmark}" ></h:outputText> </h:outputLink>
```

Comment: Corrected the little mistake, this should work now <h:outputLink value="#{item.bookmark}" rendered="#{not item.editBookmark}"><h:outputText value = "#{item.bookmark}" /></h:outputLink>

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `h:outputLink`:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{item.sno}" rendered="#{not item.editBookmark}"><f:verbatim>#{item.sno}</f:verbatim></h:outputLink>
```